# gwt-appengine app with part of its content protected and the rest public

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I have been struggling all day with an issue. I am sure there must be some easy solution that lots have already implemented as it looks to me as a basic setup.

I am building an app with GWT and appengine using requestfactory. This app has some "pages" (they are actually MVP views) that everybody should have access to. It's like the home page and a couple of views where the service we provide is described. Then if you want to use the service you have to login (with google accounts and all that). Only being logged in you have access to the rest of the views (pages) in the app. The question is, how to handle this?, the fact that some pages and some requestfactory calls are public and some other have to be available to those that have logged in?

I have already discarded the auth-constraints tags in web.xml because they work with all or nothing.

The next alternative was to use servlet filters (as the expenses demo does). That could work, but only if the "open" or not secured pages didn't need to access any data from appengine datastore (and I don't want to close that door, maybe in the future I want to show status or number of users, etc etc). The reason for this is that with request factory you only have one servlet so if you put a filter you shut down all comunication with appengine if the user is not logged in.

I was thinking of implementing this filter, with requesfactory for all the stuff once the user is logged in and also implement some RPC services for the data i might want to display in the "home or information pages" that i might need to retrieve from the datastore. However it looks a bit overkill for me.

Another alternative is to implement a check that the user is logged in all the request factory service methods that i want to protect. But that doesn't look to elegant either...

Anyone had the same problem? any ideas?

I'd appreciate any help on this.

Thanks,

Comment: It seems that other people have similar problems: http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-95318.html

Answer (score 0):

You say that the auth constraints are "all or nothing", but that's not true - they're per-url. See [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml.html#Security_and_Authentication) for details. Also, your connection of servlet filters and datastore access is a non-sequitir - the two have nothing to do with each other.